# Finding top product, average revenue, and last transaction, per customer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help in creating a function for finding (for each customer)

1. the preferred item(s)

   - The preferred item is defined as the one bought in the greatest quantity.
   - If equal, I want the one with the highest revenue.
   - If that is also equal, I want to get both/all of them.
2. the average revenue
3. the most recent transaction

- A customer is defined by his/her *mobileNumber*.

---

My data looks like this:

| mobileNumber | smartcard | country | item | Net Revenue | transaction date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 253717011202 | 25106064745190900 | Latvia | GOLD | 6779.661017 | 26/06/2021 |
| 253717011202 | 25106064745190900 | Latvia | SILVER | 5084.745763 | 17/06/2021 |
| 253717011202 | 25106064745190900 | Latvia | EXTRA | 2542.372881 | 09/04/2021 |
| 253717011202 | 25106064745190900 | Latvia | EXTRA | 2542.372881 | 10/03/2021 |
| 253717011202 | 25106064745190900 | Latvia | EXTRA | 2542.372881 | 18/02/2020 |
| 2530727013202 | 2510606474519120 | Sudan | GOLD | 2542.372881 | 09/04/2021 |
| 2530727013202 | 2510606474519120 | Sudan | GOLD | 2542.372881 | 10/03/2021 |
| 2530727013202 | 2510606474519120 | Sudan | EXTRA | 2542.372881 | 18/02/2020 |
| 12345678910 | 2311607474519120 | Zambia | GOLD | 2542.372881 | 09/04/2021 |
| 12345678910 | 2311607474519120 | Zambia | GOLD | 2542.372881 | 10/03/2021 |
| 12345678910 | 2311607474519120 | Zambia | EXTRA | 2542.372881 | 18/02/2020 |
| 12345678910 | 2311607474519120 | Zambia | EXTRA | 2542.372881 | 18/02/2020 |

---

Expected output:

| mobileNumber | smartcard | country | preferred_item | average_revenue | last_transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2530727013202 | 2510606474519120 | Sudan | GOLD | 2542.372881 | 2021-04-09 |
| 12345678910 | 2311607474519120 | Zambia | EXTRA, GOLD | 2542.372881 | 2021-04-09 |
| 253717011202 | 25106064745190900 | Latvia | EXTRA | 3898.305085 | 2021-06-26 |

Here is code to generate the data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'mobileNumber': ['253717011202', '253717011202', '253717011202', '253717011202', '253717011202', '2530727013202', '2530727013202', '2530727013202', '12345678910', '12345678910'],
        'smartcard': ['25106064745190900', '25106064745190900', '25106064745190900', '25106064745190900', '25106064745190900', '2510606474519120', '2510606474519120', '2510606474519120', '2311607474519120', '2311607474519120'],
        'country': ['Latvia', 'Latvia', 'Latvia', 'Latvia', 'Latvia', 'Sudan', 'Sudan', 'Sudan', 'Zambia', 'Zambia'],
        'item': ['GOLD', 'SILVER', 'EXTRA', 'EXTRA', 'EXTRA', 'GOLD', 'GOLD', 'EXTRA', 'GOLD', 'EXTRA'],
        'Net Revenue': [6779.661017, 5084.745763, 2542.372881, 2542.372881, 2542.372881, 2542.372881, 2542.372881, 2542.372881, 2542.372881, 2542.372881],
        'transaction date': ['26/06/2021', '17/06/2021', '09/04/2021', '10/03/2021', '18/02/2020', '09/04/2021', '10/03/2021', '18/02/2020', '09/04/2021', '10/03/2021'],
    }
)

expected_output = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'mobileNumber': [253717011202, 2530727013202, 12345678910],
        'smartcard': [25106064745190900, 2510606474519120, 2311607474519120],
        'country': ['Latvia', 'Sudan', 'Zambia'],
        'preferred_item': ['EXTRA', 'GOLD', 'EXTRA, GOLD'],
        'average_revenue': [3898.305085, 2542.372881, 2542.372881],
        'last_transaction': ['2021-06-26', '2021-04-09', '2021-04-09'],
    }
)
```

Comment: How can the customer in Zambia and Latvia have the same mobile number?

Comment: Hi Filip, This is the Sample data: my apology, we can change the number let say 12345678910 for Zambia

Comment: Why do you have both `transaction_date` and `date_yymmdd`? What is `date_yymmdd`?

Comment: The date format in yyyymmdd, was for SQL purpose, we can drop the column for this analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def preferred_items(group):
    # Count the number of occurrences of each item
    counts = group['item'].value_counts()

    # Get the most frequently purchased item(s)
    most_common_items = counts[counts == counts.max()]

    if len(most_common_items) == 1:
        # If there is only one most common item, return it
        return most_common_items.index[0]
    else:
        # Otherwise, break ties based on highest revenue
        max_revenue = group.loc[group['item'].isin(most_common_items.index), 'Net Revenue'].max()
        return ', '.join(sorted(group.loc[(group['item'].isin(most_common_items.index)) & (group['Net Revenue'] == max_revenue), 'item'].tolist()))


def average_revenue(group):
    return group['Net Revenue'].mean()


def most_recent_transaction(group):
    return pd.to_datetime(group['transaction date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').max()


output = df.groupby(['mobileNumber', 'smartcard', 'country']).apply(
    lambda group: pd.Series(
        {
            'preferred_item': preferred_items(group),
            'average_revenue': average_revenue(group),
            'last_transaction': most_recent_transaction(group),
        }
    )
).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi @Filip, that worked fine, but what if I want to have columns for average revenue and last transaction per customer?

Comment: @Mwai.John You wrote in your initial question that you was already able to do that yourself. But you still have problems with it? If so, let me know and I can adjust my answer.

Comment: yes Filip, but after I reviewed the script you shared, it came to my attention that, it will be a challenge, so if you can adjusts the answer to include Last Transaction date, and Average revenue per customer I will appreciate it.